# In Prometheus we see lot of dead space jockeys/Engineers with their chests burst open. Where are the alien creatures?

Tags: alien-franchise, prometheus

In Prometheus we see lot of dead space jockeys/Engineers with their chests burst open, so where are the alien creatures?

One possibility is that  they died of old age but we know that the evolved ones go into some sort of hibernation and can sustain it for long, at least the seeders/face-huggers can.

Comment: They’re *behind you!!!!!!!*

Answer (score 2):

I assume that they had somehow been killed by the Space Jockeys in a frantic struggle for survival.

Comment: we have safeguards around bio-research labs (UV, chemicals, etc) - it would make sense for the Engineers to have similar safeguards

Comment: Good point Horus, I guess this is one of the holes in story, looking at the potential of the black liquid, it would be an omission of epic proportions to not have safeguards (discounting the one where the just the doors close)

Comment: They could have moved on. The planet might not be lifeless, just without life in that particular area.

Answer (score 1):

theres no canonical answer but presumably the planet was either lifeless to begin with or was made lifeless by xenomorph infection and there are no nest sites around the base

the survey the ship did would also have to have not seen any evidence of a nest site to investigate

Answer (score 0):

David says about the Engineer mission to the Earth that "in order to create, you must first destroy". The Engineers planned to reuse the Earth for some other project ("to create"). This requires weapons that are fast and easy to clean up after the holocaust. The Engineers have selected some complex and rather dangerous (even for them) bio-weapon instead of, say, heavy nuclear bombardment that would render the planet unusable for they later purposes.

I think that like some human-made land mines, the beasts may have a self-destruct mechanism that disables them after the mission to destroy is complete. Then the planet is safe again after waiting for the configured time.

Giving ability for the long term hibernation would be against this goal.